# Node.js / Export configuration file

Tags: node.js

I have the following configuration file in `/etc/sysconfig/myconf`:

```
export USER=root
export NODE_DIR=/opt/MyDir
```

I want to use these setting in my `.js` file, which located in `/opt/myapplication`:

```
var userApp = //USER in /etc/sysconfig/myconf file
var dir = //NODE_DIR in /etc/sysconfig/myconf file
```

Is there any way to do it without open the file and parse it contents?

As I understand the export should give me the option to read it easily in node.js, but I don't find how (In addition, when I run `export -p`, I don't see these variables)

**EDIT**: what I search is equal Node.js's command to [source command in Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bsd-unix-source-command/) (the variables is not environment variables)

Comment: Sourcing a file means reading it and parsing its contents, but you're saying that you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If those environment variables are available when you launch the program, you can use `process.env`. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Comment: But this is not environment variables. I add some clarification to the question.